# Giving user subdirectory access without giving superdirectory access

Tags: permissions, directory

I do not have the permissions to change my `user` folder's permissions, yet I need to give a collaborator (read and write) access to the `user/foo` directory without giving them access (no read and no write) to the `user` directory. Is there any way to do this without creating a hard link?

I tried editing just the permissions of `foo` to allow collaborator read/write access but the collaborator cannot navigate to the `foo` directory because (I think) he does not have access to `user`.

Comment: In order to navigate to a directory the user needs "execute" permission on the directory.

Comment: You can't hardlink a directory either. Can't you ask your system administrator to grant the execute permission to your home directory for that user?

Comment: Crossposted: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/591166/70524